# search 2 fields in a file in another huge file, passing 2nd file only once

Tags: shell

*file1* has 100,000 lines. Each line has 2 fields such as:

```
test 12345678
test2 43213423
```

Another file has millions of lines.  Here is an example of how the above file entries look in *file2*:

```
'99' 'databases' '**test**' '**12345678**'
'1002' 'exchange' '**test2**' '**43213423**'
```

I would like a way to `grep` these 2 fields from *file1* so that I can find any line that contains both, but the gotcha is, I would like to search the 100,000 entries through the 2nd file once as looping a grep is very slow as it could loop 100,000 x 10,000,000.

Is that at all possible?

Comment: Are the fields in the second field always quoted, or only sometimes? In your example, there's no quote at the end of the first line of the second file.

Comment: whoops cut and paste error, always quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in awk:

```
awk -F"['[:blank:]]+" 'NR == FNR { a[$1,$2]; next } $4 SUBSEP $5 in a' file1 file2
```

First set the field separator so that the quotes around the fields in the second file are consumed.

The first block applies to the first file and sets keys in the array `a`. The comma in the array index translates to the control character `SUBSEP` in the key.

Lines are printed in the second file when the third and fourth fields (with the `SUBSEP` in between) match one of the keys. Due to the `'` at the start of the line, the first field `$1` is actually an empty string, so the fields you want are `$4` and `$5`.

If your fields are always quoted in the second file, then you can do this instead:

```
awk -v q="'" 'NR == FNR { a[q $1 q,q $2 q]; next } $3 SUBSEP $4 in a' file file2
```

This inserts the quotes into the array `a`, so the fields in the second file match without having to consume the quotes.

Comment: Tom, just tested this on a smaller file and it works beautifully. Many thanks.
That still looks like chinese to me and I know a bit of awk :)

edit: Just tested on a larger 2nd file (886Mb) and it is returning to the prompt with no output.....

Comment: Sorted it being dumb. Worked perfectly Tom. Many thanks.

Comment: If there's something in particular that isn't clear in the script, let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

`fgrep` and `sed` method:

```
sed "s/\b/'/g;s/\b/**/g" file1 | fgrep -f - file2
```

Modify a stream from *file1* with `sed` to match the format of the second file, (i.e. surround the fields with single quotes and asterisks), and send the stream to standard output.  The `fgrep -f -` inputs that stream as a list of *fixed strings* (but no *regexps*) and finds every matching line in *file2*.

Output:

```
'99' 'databases' '**test**' '**12345678**'
'1002' 'exchange' '**test2**' '**43213423**'
```